# Exercise on subgroup of a direct product

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Let $G= G_1 \times G_2$ be a direct product of finite groups, let $H$ be a normal subgroup of $G$ with $H \cap G_1= \{1\}$, $H \cap G_2 = \{1\}$.

Prove that $H$ is abelian.

I really don't know how to do this exercise. Hints are also appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conjugate $(a,b)\in H$ by $(c,e)$ to get the element $(cac^{-1},b)\in H$.

Can $(a,b)$ and $(cac^{-1},b)$ be distinct elements of $H$?

Comment: Could you tell me why the two elements can't be distinct? I really don't see that.

Comment: @Yaddle Given distinct $(a,b),(a',b)\in H$, consider $(a,b)^{-1}(a',b)=(a^{-1}a',e)\in H$ and the fact that $H$ intersects $G_1$ trivially.